# Web Scraper won't go to correct page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

So i keep trying to go to http://ofcc.ohio.gov/Opportunities2#lt-126679-construction-bids to get the list of bids. However the data read is always from the home page which is: http://ofcc.ohio.gov/Opportunities2. I've tried this with Beautiful Soup and Scrapy and nothing works. Any auggestions? When I curl the first url it also loads the home page data.
Code:

```
    import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://ofcc.ohio.gov/Opportunities2#lt-126679-construction-bids',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'construction%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: can you post the code you're using to do this?

Comment: import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://ofcc.ohio.gov/Opportunities2#lt-126679-construction-bids',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'construction%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

Comment: can you add this to your question ...

Answer (score 1):

Just clicking on http://ofcc.ohio.gov/Opportunities2#lt-126679-construction-bids and I'm stuck waiting for the bids to load... is this a website issue?

Are you getting any error messages? your question isn't very detailed

Comment: it sometimes won't load correctly but it still goes there most of the time. I'm not getting any error messages I just want to be able to scrape the data on Construction Bids but every time I use a link with ofcc it goes to Qualifications based RFQs

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done solely using Beautiful Soup. You could try using something like Selenium as it seems you're likely going to have to load that page and then manually click on the "Construction Bids" link.

Comment: Taking the link and loading it in an incognito window causes it to always load with "Qualification Based RFQs" as the default selection.